# Tips on Python MIL-STD-1553

Tags: python

Has anyone ever worked with MIL-STD-1553 in Python?  How did you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the 1553 interface has a Windows DLL, you can use the ctypes library to access it. I've done this for Python and my organization's 1553 products.

To start, I would write a quick test that accesses a DLL function that doesn't access the 1553 hardware, or accesses the hardware in a very simple manner. If that succeeds, then you know that you can access the DLL. Once you know you can access the DLL then you can work on getting the rest of the DLL functions to work in Python.